# Citrix with linux host and windows guest: shift key does not allways work (or to slow) for hotkeys, resulting is copy and paste experience is terrible

Tags: citrix

I am using citrix to connect from my home pc (linux/openSuse Tumbleweed) to my workstation (windows 10). This works in general but I have huge problems using copy and paste (cntrl + x/c/v) because most of the time i get old contents when pasting. Because of that I developed an annoying habit of pressing cntrl+c about five times before actually trying to paste somewhere. I also noticed when having to type special characters which need the shift key, sometimes I get the normal character on that key as if I had not pressed shift. The problem is hard to pin down but I think that the shift key is not not recognized fast enough (waiting some time with shift only pressed could work, but I do not tested this).

btw. copy and pasting of files works!

Does anyone can help me with that?